# I need help replacing Application.Find with a new function for this old macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an old 2003 xls macro that extracts data from all excel dump files in an "inbox" type subfolder. The files are generated daily and as far as I can tell from this old code, the Application.Find looks up all files it can find in this inbox and then goes through them one by one to sort the data and place it properly in the main document.

The problem of course is that Application.Find is used and does not exist in Excel anymore, requiring the use of the old Excel version to execute this macro. It's a pain to have to run an old version for the import of data and then a new version for all the other needs so I was hoping I could get some help to replace this old code with a new function that serves the same role.

I've looked around here and other places for peoples functions to find x amount of files in a given location and go through them one by one but I am not all that good at trying to integrate these more modern solutions with this older macro as it already has a structure in place to loop until all the Application.Find results have been completed.

I tried a Dir approach but was unsuccessful and I can't manage to get a filecount/array thing going so it can just work through whatever it finds in that subfolder.

```
With Application.FileSearch
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = inbox
    .SearchSubFolders = False
    .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks
    If .Execute() > 0 Then
        Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(i))
```

The expected result is that this can loop harmlessly when executed since further down in the code after having gone through the data in the opened document, it will ask for the Next i and keep going until running out of files. However, as Application.Find no longer exists, it just stops at that point with the expected error message unless I run the 2003 version.

Any help at all would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I loop through all the files in a folder:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    FilePath = "Your Path"
    FileName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls*")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)

        'Your Code

        FileName = Dir
    Loop


End Sub
```

In this case, as you can see, looking for any file which extension containts `xls` so... `xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb...`

Hope it helps

Comment: Big thanks, this seems to have done the trick. I'm gonna try it on multiple files just to make sure but since it runs through with no issues it should be good.